# C++ Square Bracket Syntax

Tags: c++

On the cppreference article about SFINAE, I came across this syntax which I do not understand:

```cpp
template <int I> void div(char(*)[I % 2 == 0] = 0) {
        // this overload is selected when I is even
}
template <int I> void div(char(*)[I % 2 == 1] = 0) {
        // this overload is selected when I is odd
}
```

I get that its a template function declaration, but I don't understand what the parameters mean. In particular, what are the square brackets in `char(*)[I % 2 == 0] = 0` and why is it equal to 0?

Comment: did you read the text just above the example? It is to illustrate "attempting to create an array of void, array of reference, array of function, array of negative size, array of non-integral size, or array of size zero. " that should be a good hint on what is going on, no?

Comment: It might be more readable to use `= nullptr` there.

Comment: @MSalters I suppose that example predates C++11, which doesn't mean that it could not be updated, but it would explain why it does not use `nullptr`. Also I am not sure about the policy on cppref, maybe using `nullptr` would only be "ok" if the section would be marked as "since C++11"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Arrays of size 0 are illegal in C++ so a particular overload is chosen based on the value of `I`: when `I` is 5, `char(*)[I % 2 == 0]` would be a pointer to an array of size `false`, i.e. zero, while the other array pointer is perfectly legal.

`= 0` is just a default ignored argument value to save you from typing `(0)` every time calling this function.

In C++20, it would be much more apparent and straightforward:

```cpp
template<int I> requires (I % 2 == 0) void div() {
}
```

And even in C++17:

```cpp
template<int I> void div() {
    if constexpr(I % 2 == 0) {
    }
    else {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When `I` is even then you have (remember that `false` converts to `0` and `true` to `1`):

```
template <int I> void div(char(*)[1] = 0) {
        // this overload is selected when I is even
}
template <int I> void div(char(*)[0] = 0) {
        // this overload is selected when I is odd
}
```

The second attempts to use an array of size `0` and according to the bullet point on that [page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae):

> The following type errors are SFINAE errors:
>
> - attempting to create an array of void, array of reference, array of function, array of
>   negative size, array of non-integral size, **or array of size zero**.

... that triggers SFINAE and the first overload is selected. The array size is `0` for the first overload when `I` is odd. Note that the parameter is unnamed. It is not used inside the function, its only purpose is to trigger SFINAE. Calling this function you need not pass the parameter because it has a default, thats the `=0`. Passing a parameter would be useless because its value isn't used anyhow.

This is a rather arcane example of SFINAE. Since C++11 you would perhaps use `std::enable_if` together with a `template <int I> is_odd;` or similar and starting from C++20 you would use concepts.